# Syntax for iterating through an array of tuples python

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

I am trying to get the tweets of a list of users into an object in Python using Tweepy, with the intention of iterating through every tweet and passing it into a text classification algorithm.

The array where the tweets are saved in, is of the form:

```
tweets = [[tweet.id_str+screen_name, 0, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]
```

So what I need is to iterate through every row of the array and get the string (the tweet text) of the third column.

**What is the proper syntax for doing it?**

Comment: This is an array of arrays, not of tuples. It doesn't matter for @BardiHarborow's answer, but perhaps worth pointing out.

Comment: In fact it's a list of lists. An [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) is something different in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you provided:

```
tweet_texts = [tweet[2].decode("utf-8") for tweet in tweets]
```

Comment: Why this does not work?

    csvtweets = [[tweet.id_str+screen_name, 0, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]
 
 tweet_texts = [csvtweets[3] for row in csvtweets]
 print tweet_texts

Instead, the output is all the 3 objects that every row/array (as @unwind said) has. Shouldn't the 3 in the brackets identify the column i want to get from every row?

Comment: @YanisKartalis, Python uses [0-based indexing](http://python-history.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html), i.e. the first element is actually referred to as the 0th element.

Comment: Thank you @Bardi Harborow ! this solved my issue :)